# Intel 82576 NIC loses PCIe link when inserting RJ45 SFP module. Can't revive it without power cycling

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.10, pcie, nic

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. Unfortunately I don't know much about all of this, so I can't tell if this problem is related to the igb driver, the firmware of the chip (eeprom?), the sfp module, the card itself or something else.

### environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10
- Kernel: 5.8.0-25-generic
- NIC: Intel 82576 EF-SFP (8086:10E7) aka E1G42EF (Serdes?)
- PXE: 1.5.89
- Driver: igb-5.6.0-k

## problem description:

Using this card with my Cisco MGBSX1 MMF SFP modules is absolutely no problem. Removing and inserting the modules, getting a connection, everything works fine.

The problem arises when I try to use my Cisco MGBT1 RJ45 SFP module.

When I insert the module, remove it and then insert it in either of the ports again, the card looses its pcie link and doesn't respond anymore.

Error:

```
igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: PCIe link lost
igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: igb: enp2s0f0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
igb 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: PCIe link lost
igb 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: igb: enp2s0f1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

Reloading the driver with `rmmod igb` and `modprobe igb` gives me the following error:

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp2s0f0 (igb): transmit queue 0 timed out
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:442 dev_watchdog+0x25b/0x270
Modules linked in: igb zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) zlua(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_core mei_hdcp snd_hwdep intel_rapl_common snd_pcm intel_pmc_bxt intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event rtsx_usb_ms snd_rawmidi memstick x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp input_leds coretemp rapl snd_seq intel_cstate snd_seq_device snd_timer serio_raw wmi_bmof efi_pstore at24 snd mei_me intel_xhci_usb_role_switch roles mei soundcore nxp_nci_i2c ucsi_acpi nxp_nci typec_ucsi nci typec nfc mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport
ip_tables x_tables autofs4 overlay nls_iso8859_1 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj uas rtsx_usb_sdmmc hid_generic usb_storage rtsx_usb usbhid i915 crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel syscopyarea aesni_intel sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops cec rc_core crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper drm psmouse r8169 xhci_pci i2c_i801 ahci lpc_ich realtek i2c_smbus dca xhci_pci_renesas libahci i2c_algo_bit wmi i2c_hid hid video [last unloaded: igb]
CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: P           O      5.8.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu
Hardware name: LENOVO 90GA003XGE/36C8, BIOS O2XKT33A 05/09/2019
RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x25b/0x270
Code: 85 c0 75 e5 eb 9c 4c 89 ff c6 05 26 85 1c 01 01 e8 2a 93 fa ff 44 89 e9 4c 89 fe 48 c7 c7 58 7a c8 b9 48 89 c2 e8 ba 30 64 ff <0f> 0b e9 7a ff ff ff 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 0f
RSP: 0018:ffffae2f40003e78 EFLAGS: 00010286
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8e8a00c068c0 RCX: 000000000000083f
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00000000000000f6 RDI: 000000000000083f
RBP: ffffae2f40003ea8 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 000000000000042c
R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8e8a00c06940
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff8e8a4ff24480 R15: ffff8e8a4ff24000
FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8e8a77c00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 00007fd3359d5000 CR3: 00000001e400a000 CR4: 00000000003406f0
Call Trace:
 <IRQ>
 ? pfifo_fast_enqueue+0x150/0x150
 call_timer_fn+0x32/0x130
 __run_timers.part.0+0x184/0x280
 ? lapic_next_deadline+0x26/0x30
 ? clockevents_program_event+0x8f/0xe0
 run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
 __do_softirq+0xd0/0x2a1
 asm_call_irq_on_stack+0x12/0x20
 </IRQ>
 do_softirq_own_stack+0x3d/0x50
 irq_exit_rcu+0x95/0xd0
 sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x3b/0x90
 asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x12/0x20
RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xb7/0x3f0
Code: 3f fb e6 46 e8 4a 5d 74 ff 48 89 45 d0 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 fa 68 74 ff 80 7d c7 00 0f 85 d3 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 e4 0f 88 df 01 00 00 49 63 d4 48 8d 04 52 48 8d 0c d5 00 00
RSP: 0018:ffffffffba203de8 EFLAGS: 00000246
RAX: ffff8e8a77c2c6c0 RBX: ffff8e8a77c36e00 RCX: 000000000000001f
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000055785785 RDI: 0000000000000000
RBP: ffffffffba203e28 R08: 0000011d7e0ab089 R09: 000000003a20a000
R10: 0000000000000e23 R11: ffff8e8a77c2b364 R12: 0000000000000007
R13: ffffffffba36adc0 R14: 0000000000000007 R15: 0000000000000000
 ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xa6/0x3f0
 cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
 cpuidle_idle_call+0x145/0x200
 do_idle+0x7a/0xe0
 cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
 rest_init+0xae/0xb0
 arch_call_rest_init+0xe/0x1b
 start_kernel+0x43a/0x45a
 x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x26
 x86_64_start_kernel+0x8b/0x8f
 secondary_startup_64+0xb6/0xc0
---[ end trace fabba6c9a6177673 ]---
```

and after that:

```
igb 0000:02:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
igb 0000:02:00.0 0000:02:00.0 (uninitialized): PCIe link lost
igb 0000:02:00.0: PHY reset is blocked due to SOL/IDER session.
igb 0000:02:00.0: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
igb: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
igb 0000:02:00.1: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
igb 0000:02:00.1 0000:02:00.1 (uninitialized): PCIe link lost
igb 0000:02:00.1: PHY reset is blocked due to SOL/IDER session.
igb 0000:02:00.1: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
igb: probe of 0000:02:00.1 failed with error -5
```

lscpi shows:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10e7] (rev ff)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10e7] (rev ff)
```

If this happens, I have to powercycle the machine to be able to use the NIC again. It's almost like the RJ45 SFP module "poisons" the ports.

If I boot with the RJ45 SFP module inserted, the port doesn't even come up in Ubuntu. The second port works fine.

Error:

```
igb: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -2
igb 0000:02:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002))
```

I can "revive" the port by taking out the RJ45 SFP module, inserting my MMF module and reloading the driver. But after that, if I insert the RJ45 module again, I lose PCIe link again.

### the working configuration

There is a configuration where this whole setup works. If I boot with empty slots, then insert the RJ45 SFP module and then the MMF module, everything works fine. The problem only occurs, when I remove the RJ45 module and the insert it in any of the slots again (or if I boot with it inserted). It's  rather unpleasent to have to do this everytime I want to reboot. I don't want to live with that, if possible.

I also tried all of this on a FreeBSD and Windows machine with a different motherboard and the error remains the same.

One more configuration that worked is loading up Ubuntu 10.04. With this version, the modules work both, if they are inserted before booting. Removing and inserting the RJ45 module again causes the same error as above. This would be an acceptable solution if Ubuntu 10.04 wasn't so old. The important aspect to me is, that the ports both work after boot with the modules already inserted.

### removing the NIC and rescanning the PCIe bus

I tried removing the NIC from the system and rescanning the PCIe bus with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474378) script a user posted on another forum. I changed it so it would remove both ports.

Unfortunately, removing works but rescanning won't bring the card back. It also doesn't show any new errors.

It also works again, if I "hotplug" it. By that I mean physically removing it from the PCIe slot and inserting it again while the machine is powered on and booted into Ubuntu.

I saved logs from everywhere (dmesg,ethtool,lspci,lshw,modinfo), let me know if you need anything more information.

I also contacted Intel via sourceforge but the Intel person said, that they don't support plugable modules in the igb driver at all anyways....this means that I can't hope for it to be fixed in a new driver version.

...I guess it could also be a wrong pcb design or firmware at this point.

The next thing on my list is to find the last kernel or driver version, where both ports work after booting with modules inserted while booting.
...and trying another RJ-45 Sfp module ofc.

**Any ideas for what else I could try?**

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the last driver that makes the RJ45-SFP module work, when already inserted before booting, is the **igb-3.0.22** from 2011. Unfortunately, you can only use this one with **2.6.x** kernels. On newer kernels it won't compile. Switching the ports still makes the card lose pcie link. I looked at the code from the next version (igb-3.1.16) and there are major changes to how the card detects different SFP media types. I don't have enough time to learn C or kernel module debugging and even if I could fix it, there is no way to carry this fix through 10 years of development and get it accepted by intel, so I returned the card to the seller.

The statement from the intel person that I talked to seems not 100% true. At some point they supported RJ45-SFP modules on this card/driver...guess they dropped it at some point or only accept certain modules now....or I'm just full of bullshit and it's actually my module that's the problem.

If anyone knows of a 1gbe SFP NIC, that is useable with RJ45-SFP modules, please let me know. I kinda don't want to use a 10gb ones because of the higher power consumption.